# Division by integer in Java yields incorrect value of 2147483

Tags: java, integer-division

This is the method I am calling to essentially calculate the mean of 1000 integers:

```
public void setMeanSampleSize(ResultData[] R) {

    double temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < R.length;i++){

        temp = temp + R[i].getTotal();
    }
    MeanSampleSize = (int) temp/R.length;
}
```

The variable Total which is part of the ResultData object is an integer.

In 99.99% of the cases, this works correctly but in some odd cases, the code yields an incorrect result of 2147483 for MeanSampleSize (which is eerily similar to 2,147,483,647 the 32-bit integer max).

Can anyone help understand why this division will work sometimes and give completely erroneous result of 2147483 on other occasions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you an idea of the input when it gives `2147483` ?

Comment: Your code is a long way to write `MeanSampleSize = (int) Stream.of(R).mapToDouble(ResultData::getTotal).average().getAsDouble();`

Comment: You talk about `int`, but your `temp` is a `double`. This isn't integer arithmeitcs, but floating point arithmetics.

Comment: Probably worth noting that `= (int) temp/R.length` is `= ((int)temp) / R.length` (integer division), not `= (int)(temp / R.length)` (double division truncating the result to `int`). It's probably not the problem, but seemed worth flagging up.

Comment: `(int) temp` will result in `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if `temp` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch or better and safer `(int) Stream.of(R).mapToDouble(ResultData::getTotal).average().orElse(0);` ;-)

Comment: Picking up on @Radiodef's comment: ...which divided by 1000 (with integer division) is...2147483! So, my "It's probably not the problem..." above was mistaken. It **is** the problem.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder and everyone else for the quick response. The value of "temp" does indeed exceed the Integer.MAX_VALUE. A simple bracket before casting to int would have saved me from my troubles I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building up your total in a `double`, and then doing this:

```
MeanSampleSize = (int) temp/R.length;
```

which is

```
MeanSampleSize = ((int) temp)/R.length;
```

As Radiodef said, if `temp`'s value is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `(int)temp` will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647), which when divided by 1000 (with integer division) is ... 2147483.

You probably wanted to divide first (as a double), then truncate to int:

```
MeanSampleSize = (int) (temp / R.length);
```

---

Worth noting the various comments, though, that doing this with a `double` probably isn't your best bet unless `getTotal` returns a `double` and you want those fractional values to accumulate. But it may be worth using a `long` (and adjusting your parens as above).